# Comparing elements from multiple lists

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, tic-tac-toe

I have 3 lists, and if say the player chose `'x'` on certain parts of the list it will print out `'Congrats X won!'` ... but somehow it says invalid syntax:

```
    elif list1 [0] , list2 [0] ,list3[0] == 'x':
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: the correct syntax would be `elif list1[0] == 'x' or list2[0] == 'x' or list3[0] == 'x'`, more cleaner `elif 'x' in (list1[0], list2[0], list3[0])`

Comment: instead of or should be and I think :) @dnit13

Comment: so in list will not work correct :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to test whether [**any**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) of the list elements equal `'x'`:

```
elif any(s[0] == 'x' for s in (list1, list2, list3)):
```

If you want to test whether [**all**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) of the list elements equal `'x'`:

```
elif all(s[0] == 'x' for s in (list1, list2, list3)):
```

Comment: I managed to make 2 players take turn playing but it stops after the 2nd player entered her answer. I want to do the While loop however I seriously ran out of idea how to. I get it in my mind like I want the two players to keep playing until 3 position of 0s or Xs are filled but putting it in code I really need help.

Comment: That doesn't really have anything to do with this question; you'll need to ask another one. To increase your chances of getting a helpful answer, please read [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).